# How to create custom action for an object?

Tags: java

I have an object, let's say FOO, with a variable, percent...

I need to create an Action percentChanged, which will be triggered when the variable percent is changed, which will handled by an ActionListener in another object ...

How to do it in java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a PropertyChangeListener. This is the way Java beans work.

Comment: This is my preferred approach when the problem is this simple.  I would use coobird's solution if the event flow were more complex.

Comment: PCLs are almost certainly the way to go here - it will allow easy integration with binding libraries as well (see Better Beans Binding)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Checkout [`Observable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) and [`Observer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html)

Comment: Really, don't use `Observer` and `Observable`.

Comment: Humm, Why? Can you give an article that explains why one shouldn't use these?

Comment: I'm with Tom.  Observable is messy as you end up downcasting and Observer is a concrete class you have to extend, which isn't always possible.  At least with the PropertyChangeListener approach you can handle primtives more cleanly and are told the name of the property too.

Answer (score 2):

The `ActionListener` interface only has the `actionPerformed` method, so what you're trying to accomplish may be implemented by creating your own listener interface and having your `Foo` class notify the registered listeners.

For example, a new interface called `PercentChangeListener` could be created:

```
interface PercentChangeListener {
  public void percentChanged();
}
```

Then, the `Foo` class can have ways to register the `PercentChangeListener`s which should be notified when the percentage changes:

```
class Foo {
  // Percentage.
  private Percent percent;

  // Listeners which should be notified of a change to the percentage.
  private List<PercentageChangeListener> listeners;

  // Adds a listener that should be notified.
  public void addListener(PercentageChangeListener listener) {
    listener.add(listener);
  }

  // Notifies all the listeners which should be told that the percentage
  // has changed.
  private void notifyListeners() {
    for (PercentageChangeListener listener : listeners) {
      listener.percentChanged();
    }
  }

  // Some process which changes the percentage.
  private void someProcess() {
    percent.change();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Then, any object which should be notified of a change in the percentage of `Foo` should implement `PercentChangeListener` or have an handler to handle it:

```
class ClassThatHandlesFoo {

  public void someMethod() {
    Foo f = new Foo();
    f.addPercentageChangeListener(this);
  }

  public void percentChanged() {
    // Perform action when percent of "Foo f" has changed.
  }
}
```

The above is untested code, but should give an idea on the approach which could be taken.

Comment: You need to extend EventListener as in interface PercentChangeListener extends EventListener

Comment: I would implement percentChanged to accept either an event object or the old and new values of the percentage.  That way notified clients do not need to make a call back to the event source to read the new percentage value.  I'd also advise using a CopyOnWriteArrayList to hold your list of listeners.  This avoids ConcurrentModificationExceptions being thrown if a listener attempts to remove iself from within the percentChanged callback.